# how add second (hidden) value to cell in datatables.net?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

Scenario: I want to send selected cell's values to a controller with POST.
how can I send two value for every selected cells ;that one value is visible and other is hidden?

for example each cell contain Time & Date that only time is shown in datatable.
i want to post both time and date.

is there any complete example to use mData & fnGetData?

this is my code:

```
$('#example').DataTable({
                "ajax": 'api/Tcal',
                "iDisplayLength": '100',
                "columns": [

                    { "data": "id" },
                    { "data": "shanbeh" },
                    { "data": "yekShanbeh" },
                    { "data": "dooShanbeh" },
                    { "data": "sehShanbeh" },
                    { "data": "charShanbeh" },
                    { "data": "panjShanbeh" },
                    { "data": "jommeh" },
                ],
                language: {
                    url: '/lib/datatables/js/Persian.json'
                },
                select: {
                    style: 'multi',
                    items: 'cell'
                }
            });
        });

        $("#Button1").click(function () {
            var oData = $("#example").DataTable().cells({ selected: true }).data().toArray();
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "api/TGCells",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json;",
                data: JSON.stringify({ data: oData }),
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a closer look at the [tour], especially the part about not asking "_questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)_". Also take a look at [ask].

Comment: You can [edit] your question to show us what you have tried, what code and data you are using, and what actually happens when you run it.

Comment: thanks andrewjames. I edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach:

**Step 1**

Alter the DataTable so that it stores two values in each cell, using two `<span>` elements, where the data in one of the spans is hidden:

```html
<td>
  <span class="part_one">my first value</span>
  <span class="part_two" hidden>my second value</span>
</td>
```

You can do this using a column renderer in your DataTable:

```js
"render": function ( data, type, row ) {
  if ( type === "display" ) {
    return '<span class="part_one">' + data + 
      '</span><span class="part_two" hidden>' + row.id + 
      '</span>';
  } else {
    return data; // for sorting and filtering, just use the main value
  }
}
```

**Step 2**

In your button function you can access the DataTable nodes, instead of the cells, to get access to the inner HTML containing the `<span>` elements:

```js
$("#Button1").click(function () {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable();
  var nodes = table.cells( {selected:true} ).nodes().toArray(); 
  nodes.forEach( (node) => { 
    var partOne = $(node).find('span.part_one').text();
    var partTwo = $(node).find('span.part_two').text();
    console.log( partOne, ':', partTwo );
  } );
} );
```

Once you have each value in a separate variable, you can build your Ajax request, as needed.

---

**Full example:**

This uses a test Ajax response, for building the DataTable:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

  <!-- select extension -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.3/css/select.dataTables.min.css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.3/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div style="margin: 20px;">

    <table id="example" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
    </table>

    <br>

    <button id="Button1">Click Me</button>

</div>

<script>
 
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: {
      method: "GET",
      url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
      dataSrc: "",  
    },
    "columns": [
      { "title": "User ID", "data": "userId" },
      { 
        "title": "Title", 
        "data": "title",
        "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
          if ( type === "display" ) {
            return '<span class="part_one">' + data + 
              '</span><span class="part_two" hidden>' + row.id + 
              '</span>';
          } else {
            return data;
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    select: {
      style: 'multi',
      items: 'cell'
    }
  });

} );

$("#Button1").click(function () {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable();
  var nodes = table.cells( {selected:true} ).nodes().toArray(); 
  nodes.forEach( (node) => { 
    var partOne = $(node).find('span.part_one').text();
    var partTwo = $(node).find('span.part_two').text();
    console.log( partOne, ':', partTwo );
  } );
} );

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Select two or more cells from the "Title" column and then click the button (at the bottom of the page).